# How do I define value of discriminator for coproduct codecs?

Tags: scala, scodec, coproduct

Could you please explain how coproducts really work? Here is my code

```
sealed trait ArdbData

case class ArdbDataString(value: String) extends ArdbData

case class ArdbDataLong(value: Long) extends ArdbData

case class ArdbDataDouble(value: Double) extends ArdbData

object ArdbDataString {
  implicit val codec: Codec[ArdbDataString] = // ... some codec here
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[ArdbData, ArdbDataString, Int] = Discriminator(6)
}

object ArdbDataLong {

  implicit val codec: Codec[ArdbDataLong] = // ... some codec here
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[ArdbData, ArdbDataLong, Int] = Discriminator(1)
}

object ArdbDataDouble {
  implicit val codec: Codec[ArdbDataDouble] = // ... some codec here
  implicit val discriminator: Discriminator[ArdbData, ArdbDataDouble, Int] = Discriminator(2)
}

object ArdbData {
  implicit val discriminated: Discriminated[ArdbData, Int] = Discriminated(uint8)

  import shapeless.syntax.singleton._

//  implicit val codec: Codec[ArdbData] = Codec.coproduct[ArdbData].discriminatedBy(uint8).using(
//    'ArdbDataString ->> 4 :: 'ArdbDataLong ->> 1 :: 'ArdbDataDouble ->> 2 :: HNil)
}
```

I thought I have to define coproduct codec for `ArdbData` as demonstrated in [this test](https://github.com/scodec/scodec/blob/1b51857832d54edc9a617da95fed4094776b6bfe/shared/src/test/scala/scodec/examples/CoproductsExample.scala#L118-L141). Also I need to use particular IDs for each subtype which I defined in `discriminatedBy.using()`. When I started testing it I suddenly found keys from `.using` are not used. Instead ID from each `Discriminator` instance is used. Then I commented out `Codec.coproduct[ArdbData]` and it still compiles! Why does it compile ? What's the right way of defining value of discriminator ?